# graph-refactoring of an TEI-xml-Textgraph

Tags: xml, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to do a graph-refactoring to a TEI-XML-textfile which I imported into neo4j. For importing this XML you need this special apoc-library (only version 3.2, thanks to Stefan Armbruster):
https://seafile.rlp.net/f/bf9fbe3cde30491ea26a/?dl=1

Then you can import a sample graph, which consists only of three pages of the original document:

```
CALL apoc.xml.import('https://seafile.rlp.net/f/5db7bdc77c5447faad88/?dl=1', {createNextWorkRelationships: true}) yield node return node;
```

This model shows a TEI-XML-Text as a hierarchic tree in the graph. The document starts with the XML-Document-node, the text-nodes are connected with NEXT_WORD-edges and the XML-elements can be found following the NEXT-edges.

Now I want to find pairs of XmlTag-nodes with the _name-property 'lb' (the lb-element marks the lines of a text). Now I want to create a new node of the type `line` for each line which connects to the first and last xmlWord-node of each line with FIRST_CHILD_OF- and LAST_CHILD_OF-edges.